# IControllerFactory vs IControllerActivator asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have faced some kind of confusion with `IControllerFactory` and `IControllerActivator`. I was trying to create controllers manually because it is required by my project. So, I looked at the Microsoft documentation. However, descriptions for both interfaces are confusing.

Descriptions for each interface

**[IControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.icontrollerfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2)**:
`Provides methods for the creation and disposal of controllers.`

**[IControllerActivator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.icontrolleractivator?view=aspnetcore-2.2)**:
`Provides methods to create a controller.`

Both are saying that they provide methods to create controllers. So, if I want to create a controller manually, which interface should I use? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: It looks they differ in terms of disposal. So when you do not need to take care for disposal the second could be your choice. Otherwise the first.

Comment: The role of the `ControllerFactory` is to provide a ready-to-use controller instance. In order to do that, internally it relies on the `ControllerActivator` to *construct* the desired type and then continues the *creation* of the controller by further configuring more of its properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a controller instance,  ASP.NET Core obtains an instance of `IControllerFactory` and uses it for controller creation.

However, if you look at the ASP.NET Core [DefaultControllerFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs) implementation, you will see that both the `IControllerFactory` and `IControllerActivator` are actually used for controller creation, because `DefaultControllerFactory` uses `IControllerActivator` to create an instance of the controller.

`DefaultControllerFactory` requires a dependency of type `IControllerActivator` to be passed in the constructor:

```cs
public DefaultControllerFactory(
    IControllerActivator controllerActivator,
    IEnumerable<IControllerPropertyActivator> propertyActivators)
{
    if (controllerActivator == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(controllerActivator));
    }

    if (propertyActivators == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyActivators));
    }

    _controllerActivator = controllerActivator;
    _propertyActivators = propertyActivators.ToArray();
}
```

and `CreateController` and `ReleaseController` methods basically just invoke the `IControllerActivator`'s corresponding methods:

```cs
public object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
{
    ... some null checks

    // _controllerActivator is of type IControllerActivator
    var controller = _controllerActivator.Create(context);
    foreach (var propertyActivator in _propertyActivators)
    {
        propertyActivator.Activate(context, controller);
    }

    return controller;
}
```

```cs
public void ReleaseController(ControllerContext context, object controller)
{
    ... some null checks

    _controllerActivator.Release(context, controller);
}
```

The only additional thing that the default instance of `IControllerFactory` does is invoking property activators (instances of `IControllerPropertyActivator`).

**What you can do in your case?**

- **Option 1**: Provide your own implementation of `IControllerFactory` and create controller instances however you want. In this case `IControllerActivator` will not be used unless you require it.
- **Option 2**: Use the default implementation of `IControllerFactory`, but provide your own implementation of `IControllerActivator` which will be used by `DefaultControllerFactory`.

Comment: I'm in a static HtmlHelper class, and i'm trying to new up these activators, but i need ITypeActivatorCache which i can't figure out how to create it. I have a question here that is related. I'm stuck, any help would be much appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620624/net-core-security-trimming-using-authorized-attribute-on-controller-methods

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time if I have such questions, I will check at the interfaces itself.
[image: Factory]

[image: Activator]

Seeing this, it tells me that the `Factory` is for execution and the `Activator` for action.